# Interpolating but fixing a range in R

Tags: r

I get some extreme values in the beginning and in the end when interpolating.

In fact, the last b **values should not be greater than max(b)**, and the **first values should not be less than 0**.

data example:

```r
a<-c(1, 3, 4, 6, 8.7, 9, 10, 12, 19.3, 20)
b<-c(10, 30, 40, 60, 87, 90, 100, 120, 190, 200)
df<-data.frame(a=a, b=b)
> df
      a   b
1   1.0  10
2   3.0  30
3   4.0  40
4   6.0  60
5   8.7  87
6   9.0  90
7  10.0 100
8  12.0 120
9  19.3 190
10 20.0 200
```

This is the code I'm using right now:

```r
Hmisc::approxExtrap(df$a, df$b, xout = c(0:25))
```

Comment: So i'm confused, so you want extrapolation outside the observed range? You seem to be clipping it back to the observed range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in `pmin` and `pmax`:

```
pmin(max(df$b), pmax(min(df$b), approxExtrap(df$a, df$b, xout = c(0:25))))
```

This will keep the upper and lower bounds of `b`. If you want to replace the lower bound of `b` (currently 1) with `0`, replace `min(df$b)` with `0`.